# Ошибка при выводе максимально большой цифры из рандомного числа

Tags: python, алгоритм, циклы

```py
from random import random

num = print(int(random() * 10000 + 1000))
#num = input()
maxDigit = -1
print(num)

strNum = str(num)

for i in range(len(strNum)):
    if strNum[i] >= strNum[1] and strNum[i] >= strNum[2] and strNum[i] >= strNum[3] and strNum[i] >= strNum[0]:
        maxDigit = strNum[i]
print(maxDigit)
```

Вот небольшой код. Проблема в том что если вводить вручную число а не рандомно 
то всьо ок, а если число рандомно генерируется то видает ошыбку. И вот вопрос как её исправить
[image: Вот она]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`num = print(int(random() * 10000 + 1000))` этот код сделает `num = None`, т.к. `print` возвращает `None`

С учетом, того как ваш код выглядит с `input`, думаю вы хотели что-то такое:

```
...
num = int(random() * 10000 + 1000)
print(num)

maxDigit = -1
...
```

А с учетом вашей задачи (вывод самой большой цифры из числа), то я бы сделал так:

```
num = int(random() * 10000 + 1000)
print(num)
print(max(str(num)))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое